# JavaFX MediaPlayer: plays half as many times it should when setStopTime is used

Tags: java, javafx

When `setStopTime` is used on my `MediaPlayer`, the media plays about half as many times as is specified by `setCycleCount`.

So if I use `player.setCycleCount(10)`, the sound plays only about 5 times instead of 10.

**Why is the player acting this way, and how do I make it play the intended number of times?**

I did more tests and it seems that after playing once, `currentCount` is increased by 2 instead of 1, and `OnEndOfMedia` is triggered twice too.

The problem seems to be limited to some of the medias. Examples:

https://ia601701.us.archive.org/21/items/Laser_201304/laser.mp3 (about 1.8 seconds long)
https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3 (about 27 seconds long)

The problem disappear if I stop using `setStopTime`.

Here is a complete example of the problem. Notice how the sound is not played 10 times, and how on most cycles the text is printed twice to the console.

```java
package main;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.media.Media;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer;
import javafx.scene.media.MediaView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Media media = new Media("https://ia601701.us.archive.org/21/items/Laser_201304/laser.mp3");
        MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer(media);

        // Add to scene
        Group root = new Group(new MediaView(player));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 500, 200);

        // Show the stage
        primaryStage.setTitle("Media Player");
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        player.setCycleCount(10); // should run 10 times, but runs 5-8 times
        player.setStopTime(new Duration(1800)); // removing this fixes the issue

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        player.setOnEndOfMedia(
                new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        float sec = (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) / 1000F;
                        System.out.println("Current Count: " + player.getCurrentCount() + " Seconds: " + sec);
                    }
                });
        player.play();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Example of output:

```
Current Count: 1 Seconds: 3.456
Current Count: 2 Seconds: 3.465
Current Count: 3 Seconds: 5.334
Current Count: 4 Seconds: 7.177
Current Count: 5 Seconds: 7.185
Current Count: 6 Seconds: 9.056
Current Count: 7 Seconds: 10.896
Current Count: 8 Seconds: 10.906
Current Count: 9 Seconds: 12.776
Current Count: 10 Seconds: 12.798
```

Notice how `OnEndOfMedia` is often triggered in quick succession, for example 1-2, 4-5, 7-8, and 9-10 (in this case the media played 6 times).

I tried with JavaFX 10, 11 and 13 and I get the same issue.

EDIT: I've noticed that for problematic medias, `getCurrentTime()` always return the maximum duration of the media.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem with your code and MP3 file. However, the problem does not occur if the `stopTime` is set sufficiently before the actual duration of the MP3 file. This leads me to conclude the problem is the caused by the `stopTime` being set too close to the actual duration of the media. This _may_ be a concurrency issue; as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/get-started-tutorial/jfx-architecture.htm#A1107438), there's a separate "media thread" for actually playing the media—but looking at the implementation, the repeat functionality occurs on the FX thread

Comment: Consider [submitting a bug report](https://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/) if one doesn't [already exist](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/projects/JDK/issues/JDK-8213225?filter=allopenissues) (also see [here](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx)). Also, note that for short sound effects, such as a 1.8 second laser sound, using an [`AudioClip`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/12/javafx.media/javafx/scene/media/AudioClip.html) may be more appropriate.

Comment: It also does it for larger files too.

Comment: How close to the end of the file did you set the `stopTime`? If close (i.e. near identical), then I'm not surprised. As mentioned, I suspect this is a concurrency issue, which means the length of the file is irrelevant. The problem, I believe, is that the media thread reaches the `stopTime`, which schedules a repeat on the FX thread, which in turn must post a "seek to `startTime`" back to the media thread. However, before that can take effect, the media thread reaches the end of the file, triggering another repeat procedure—causing two repeat cycles to occur "simultaneously".

Comment: I see. What's the recommended option for resetting the `stopTime` to its default, then?

Comment: Have you tried calling `setStopTime(null)`?

Comment: If I do I get a java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Hmm. Well, I can't get it to work properly using `Duration.UNKNOWN`, `Duration.INDEFINITE`, `Media#getDuration()`, or `null`. I think this behavior is simply a bug and you'll have to wait for them to fix it, if they ever do. For now, I suppose a workaround might be to create a new `MediaPlayer` when you want to remove any previously set `stopTime`. I noticed a bug report was submitted (I assume by you) and accepted which was assigned a priority of P4: [JDK-8230887](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8230887).

Comment: If you look at the comment to that issue, you'll see they're leaning towards documenting the behavior that setting the stop time equal to the duration is incorrect—and might prevent it altogether. It doesn't appear to be clear to them that one might want to remove/reset the stop time of a `MediaPlayer` instance. I don't have an account with them, so I can't comment; not sure how to communicate after an issue has been submitted... maybe through the mailing list?

Comment: I would hope the javafx team at least finds a way to reset the stop time without triggering the bug.